# Subversion errors when committing: "svn: Can't open file ... no such file or directory"

Tags: svn

I have a large code base where many changes have been made, but it has been a while since the code has been committed. When I tried to commit, I run into the following error:

> svn: Can't open file
>   '/var/www/html/trunk/folder/.svn/text-base/file.php.svn-base': No such
>   file or directory

`/var/www/html/trunk/folder/file.php` exists, but `/var/www/html/trunk/folder/.svn/text-base/file.php.svn-base` does not. I'm not sure why I have several folders within my codebase that are missing corresponding `.svn-base` files, but I do.

To get around the issue, I can do the following:

```
cd /var/www/html/trunk/folder
svn rm --keep-local --force file.php
svn commit file.php
svn add file.php
svn commit file.php
```

Now `file.php` is in good standing and there is a corresponding `.svn/text-base/file.php.svn-base` file.

If I try to commit my full codebase again, it'll run into the next ...

> "svn: Can't open file ... No such file or directory"

... error, and I don't know how many there are. It could take hours to go about this the way to correct all of the errors.

1) Is there a way to fix all of these issues in one go? Or better yet, is the underlying issue something else that needs to be fixed?

2) If not, anyone have any ideas for how to do this faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you do an `svn up` after your commit to see if anything changes? Another thing to try would be to checkout a pristine copy of your trunk, add the file 'file.php' to it, and commit. Then go to your weird trunk working copy and do an `svn up` there.

Comment: Try asking at http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html (users@subversion.apache.org to be precise).

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke nothing changes. Your suggestion is another way to do what I'm doing, but I'd have to do that for all of the changes in the codebase. More and more thinking an svn export and starting over is what I need to do.

Comment: @bahrep thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are using some version of unix. The user account that you are using does not have permission to read/write to the file. Check your permissions.

Comment: I've tried all sorts of permission/user combinations. I'm logged in as root, chown'd it to root:root and chmod'd it to 777 and still get the error. Shouldn't that have been enough to get it to work?